# difficulty with Python

Tags: python

```
def myfunc(x):
 y = x
 y.append('How do I stop Python from modifying x here?')
 return y

x = []
z = myfunc(x)
print(x)
```

Comment: This will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/python-how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference

Comment: People who are downvoting my question:
How should I have known about this?
The style I gave would work in every other language I have used.

Comment: @ricky: I rarely downvote and didn't here, but in answer to your question, you are right Python assignment is different than many other languages, but I'm guessing the downvoters are thinking something like "RTFM". Regardless, for your own sake, don't sweat one downvoted question (if it happens a bunch, you should probably try to figure out why).

Comment: @Ricky, I'm no downvoter either, but note that in Java -- perhaps the single most widespread programming language, certainly the most taught in college today -- assignment is by reference, just like in Python.  Perhaps the downvoters just intrinsically think in those terms (rather than, say, in terms of Fortran, Pascal, C, ...).

Comment: @Ricky Demer You should edit the title. "Difficulty with Python" could be anything.

Comment: Bad title, but valid question. I'm giving it +1 to counter the downvoters.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You do:

```
y = x[:]
```

to make a copy of list `x`.

Comment: It's worth noting that the copy is shallow.

Answer (score 1):

You need to copy X before you modify it,

```
def myfunc(x):
 y = list(x)
 y.append('How do I stop Python from modifying x here?')
 return y

x = []
z = myfunc(x)
print(x)
```